# Transforming shp files to projected coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, albania

I have some KML files, polylines. I will convert them in grass to shp. How can I transform coordinates to some projected coordinate system? I was never doing it, so please help me. I need to transform them to Albanian 1987 GK Zone 4. I'm using Autocad Map 3D 2010 or ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to make sure your converted kml/shapefile has **spatial reference or a .prj file first as GCS_WGS_1984** (Google Earth projection).  You can define this projection using the Define Projection tool in ArcToolbox, or in ArcCatolog you can go to the properties of the layer and assign its spatial reference.  After you do this you can then use the Project tool within the Data Management Toolbox to reproject your layer to Albanian 1987 (Albanian 1987 is located at: Geographic Coordinate Systems>Europe folder).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that wanted projection is [EPSG:2199](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2199/) (Albanian 1987 GK Zone 4)

It would be pretty easy to transform it with ogr2ogr (not tested) :

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /path/to/your/output.shp path/input.kml
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:EPSG:2199 /path/to/your/output_epsg2199.shp /path/to/your/output.shp
```

1. The first command convert your kml to a shapefile
2. The second re-project your shapefile to Albanian 1987 GK Zone 4

Have a look on [GDAL/OGR website](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Projections_and_Transformations_toolset/001700000075000000/) should help you out.

You'll likely want to use the Project tool in the Data Management Toolbox.